JavaScript - Make SHA256 hash from another JS script result
I need help with creating JS script for making SHA256 hash from another JS script result. I need to make SHA256 hash from result of this script;
function test(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(test(16));

Someone with decent knowledge in basic cryptography and JS, reply this question.
I tried doing it by copying this script from another Stack Overflow user;
var makeserverseed = function sha256(ascii) {
  function rightRotate(value, amount) {
      return (value>>>amount) | (value<<(32 - amount));
  };
  
  var mathPow = Math.pow;
  var maxWord = mathPow(2, 32);
  var lengthProperty = 'length'
  var i, j;
  var result = ''

  var words = [];
  var asciiBitLength = ascii[lengthProperty]*8;
  
  var hash = sha256.h = sha256.h || [];
  var k = sha256.k = sha256.k || [];
  var primeCounter = k[lengthProperty];

  var isComposite = {};
  for (var candidate = 2; primeCounter < 64; candidate++) {
      if (!isComposite[candidate]) {
          for (i = 0; i < 313; i += candidate) {
              isComposite[i] = candidate;
          }
          hash[primeCounter] = (mathPow(candidate, .5)*maxWord)|0;
          k[primeCounter++] = (mathPow(candidate, 1/3)*maxWord)|0;
      }
  }
  
  ascii += '\x80'
  while (ascii[lengthProperty]%64 - 56) ascii += '\x00' 
  for (i = 0; i < ascii[lengthProperty]; i++) {
      j = ascii.charCodeAt(i);
      if (j>>8) return; 
      words[i>>2] |= j << ((3 - i)%4)*8;
  }
  words[words[lengthProperty]] = ((asciiBitLength/maxWord)|0);
  words[words[lengthProperty]] = (asciiBitLength)
  
  for (j = 0; j < words[lengthProperty];) {
      var w = words.slice(j, j += 16); 
      var oldHash = hash;
      hash = hash.slice(0, 8);
      
      for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
          var i2 = i + j;
          var w15 = w[i - 15], w2 = w[i - 2];
          var a = hash[0], e = hash[4];
          var temp1 = hash[7]
              + (rightRotate(e, 6) ^ rightRotate(e, 11) ^ rightRotate(e, 25)) // S1
              + ((e&hash[5])^((~e)&hash[6])) // ch
              + k[i]
              + (w[i] = (i < 16) ? w[i] : (
                      w[i - 16]
                      + (rightRotate(w15, 7) ^ rightRotate(w15, 18) ^ (w15>>>3)) // s0
                      + w[i - 7]
                      + (rightRotate(w2, 17) ^ rightRotate(w2, 19) ^ (w2>>>10)) // s1
                  )|0
              );
          var temp2 = (rightRotate(a, 2) ^ rightRotate(a, 13) ^ rightRotate(a, 22)) // S0
              + ((a&hash[1])^(a&hash[2])^(hash[1]&hash[2])); // maj
          
          hash = [(temp1 + temp2)|0].concat(hash);
          hash[4] = (hash[4] + temp1)|0;
      }
      
      for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          hash[i] = (hash[i] + oldHash[i])|0;
      }
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (j = 3; j + 1; j--) {
          var b = (hash[i]>>(j*8))&255;
          result += ((b < 16) ? 0 : '') + b.toString(16);
      }
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(makeserverseed);

For example let's say that my random string from 1st script is 'SLvZAfpv2zEPYg5F', I need to make SHA256 hash for it in JavaScript and console log it. The hash for SHA256 of 'SLvZAfpv2zEPYg5F' is: "2ab51f5928246656e753f6518dea0e0745c8faf9429578136c13181bb36d926b" and I need to find a way to display it in my console. Thanks in advance!

remove the var makeserverseed = from teh code you posted, then just call console.log(sha256('SLvZAfpv2zEPYg5F')) and you'll see the code you posted does what you need

If i get you right, I can make line: let textforHash = 'SLvZAfpv2zEPYg5f', delete "var makeserverseed =" and on bottom of the script put: console.log(sha256(textforHash));?

Yes, that is what I am suggesting

For smaller input it won't matter, but implementing SHA-256 in JS will be a lot less performant than calling a function that has a native implementation / SHA-256 CPU support backing it - and I'd rather use a well tested library for anything to do with cryptography.

You are suggesting that I should learn about SHA-256 CPU support for future? I'm new to cryptography world and want to learn as much as possible.

@MaartenBodewes - while your comment is valid, for this use case, a 16 character string isn't going to stress any computer built in the last 40 years :p

@jordimetil - you don't need to learn about SHA-256 CPU support - what you should know is that modern javascript engines have "native" crypto functions, as shown in the answer below (e.g. crypto.subtle) which will benefit from being native code rather than interpreted javascript

@JaromandaX 40 years ago I just got my 8 bit 64kiB MSX computer at 3.5MHz (4 cycles per instruction). If you programmed SHA-256 in basic you'd wait forever for it to finish. But even MD5 wasn't invented back then, so...

@MaartenBodewes - I may have exaggerated the years :p

I'm working on projects where inputs is not that big (32-character string max.), is it good to implement SHA-256 script in JavaScript?

If you are in a secure context then this should work:


function sha256(input) {
  const buffer = new TextEncoder().encode(input);
  return ( 
    crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', buffer)
    .then(hashBuffer => {
      const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
      const hashHex = hashArray.map(byte => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
      return hashHex;
    })
  );
}
 
// And to use

const textToHash = 'want to hash this string';

sha256(textToHash)
  .then(hashed => {
    console.log('hashed', hashed);
    // do stuff here
  })
  .catch(console.log);



The docs MDN SubtleCrypto

why not put 'SLvZAfpv2zEPYg5F' as the value for textToHash to show that it is producing the expected result :p

If you are in a secure context - and if OP isn't, then the code he posted will work :p
